# Automator/Apple Script: Move files with same prefix on a new folder. The folder name must be the files prefix

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal

I'm a photographer and  I have multiple jpg files of clothings in one folder. The files name structure is:

**TYPE_FABRIC_COLOR (Example: BU23W02CA_CNU_RED, BU23W02CA_CNU_BLUE, BU23W23MG_LINO_WHITE)**

I have to move files of same TYPE (BU23W02CA) on one folder named as TYPE.

For example:

> **MAIN FOLDER>**
>
> **BU23W02CA_CNU_RED.jpg, BU23W02CA_CNU_BLUE.jpg, BU23W23MG_LINO_WHITE.jpg**

Became:

> **MAIN FOLDER>**
>
> **BU23W02CA_CNU > BU23W02CA_CNU_RED.jpg, BU23W02CA_CNU_BLUE.jpg**
>
> **BU23W23MG_LINO > BU23W23MG_LINO_WHITE.jpg**

Comment: `mkdir BU23W02CA_CNU; mv BU23W02CA_CNU* BU23W02CA_CNU`

Comment: You should take the [tour] and read [ask].  Your question risks being closed.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry this is my first question.

Comment: I have hunderd of files with different names. Can in read file name ed extract "type" and "fabric"? They are between "_" character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some scripts.

**V1**

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    # Extract the directory name
    dirname=$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f1-2 | sed 's#\./\(.*\)#\1#')
    #DEBUG echo "$file --> $dirname"

    # Create it if not already existing
    if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
    then
        mkdir "$dirname"
    fi

    # Move the file into it
    mv "$file" "$dirname"
done
```

- it assumes all files that the `find` lists are of the format you described in your question, i.e. `TYPE_FABRIC_COLOR.ext`.
- `dirname` is the extraction of the first two words delimited by `_` in the file name.
- since `find` lists the files with a `./` prefix, it is removed from the `dirname` as well (that is what the `sed` command does).
- the `find` specifies the name of the files to consider as `*.jpg`.  You can change this to something else, if you want to restrict which files are considered in the move.
- this version loops through each file, creates a directory with it's first two sections (if it does not exists already), and moves the file into it.
- if you want to see what the script is doing to each file, you can add option `-v` to the `mv` command.  I used it to debug.

However, since it loops though each file one by one, this might take time with a large number of files, hence this next version.

---

**V2**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r dirname
do
    echo ">$dirname"

    # Create it if not already existing
    if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
    then
        mkdir "$dirname"
    fi

    # Move the file into it
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${dirname}_*" -exec mv {} "$dirname" \;
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print | sed 's#^\./\(.*\)_\(.*\)_.*\..*$#\1_\2#' | sort | uniq)
```

- this version loops on the directory names instead of on each file.
- the last line does the "magic".  It `find`s all files, and extracts the first two words (with `sed`) right away.  Then these words are `sort`ed and "`uniq`ued".
- the `while` loop then creates each directory one by one.
- the `find` inside the `while` loop moves all files that match the directory being processed into it.  Why did I not simply do `mv ${dirname}_* ${dirname}`?  Since the expansion of the `*` wildcard could result in a too long arguments list for the `mv` command.  Doing it with the `find` ensures that it will work even on LARGE number of files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I understand the code but I have a question. How can I use this inside Automator? Can I create an app that ask for input folder?

Comment: Sorry, cannot help with Automator, I do not use an Apple computer.

Comment: no problem, it works perfectly with the terminal. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting oneliner `awk` script:

```
echo "$(ls -1 *.jpg)"| awk '{system("mkdir -p "$1 OFS $2);system("mv "$0" "$1 OFS $2)}' FS=_ OFS=_
```

#### Explanation:

`echo "$(ls -1 *.jpg)"`: List all jpg files in current directory one file per line

`FS=_` : Set `awk` field separator to `_` $1=type $2=fabric $3=color.jpg

`OFS=_` : Set `awk` output field separator to `_`

##### awk script explanation

```
{ # for each file name from list
  system ("mkdir -p "$1 OFS $2); # execute "mkdir -p type_fabric"
  system ("mv " $0 " " $1 OFS $2); # execute "mv current-file to type_fabric"
}
```